# How to return full row using Slick's insertOrUpdate

Tags: scala, slick-3.0, playframework-2.5

I am currently learning Play2, Scala and Slick 3.1, and am pretty stuck with the syntax for using insertOrUpdate and wonder if anyone can please help me.

What I want to do is to return the full row when using insertOrUpdate including the auto inc primary key, but I have only managed to return the number of updated/inserted rows.

Here is my table definition:

```html
package models

final case class Report(session_id: Option[Long], session_name: String, tester_name: String, date: String, jira_ref: String,
                  duration: String, environment: String, notes: Option[String])

trait ReportDBTableDefinitions {

  import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._

  class Reports(tag: Tag) extends Table[Report](tag, "REPORTS") {

    def session_id = column[Long]("SESSION_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def session_name = column[String]("SESSION_NAME")
    def tester_name = column[String]("TESTER_NAME")
    def date = column[String]("DATE")
    def jira_ref = column[String]("JIRA_REF")
    def duration = column[String]("DURATION")
    def environment = column[String]("ENVIRONMENT")
    def notes = column[Option[String]]("NOTES")

    def * = (session_id.?, session_name, tester_name, date, jira_ref, duration, environment, notes) <> (Report.tupled, Report.unapply)
  }

  lazy val reportsTable = TableQuery[Reports]

}
```

Here is the section of my DAO that relates to insertOrUpdate, and it works just fine, but only returns the number of updated/inserted rows:

```html
package models

import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import scala.concurrent.Future

class ReportsDAO @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends DAOSlick {

  import driver.api._

  def save_report(report: Report): Future[Int] = {
    dbConfig.db.run(reportsTable.insertOrUpdate(report).transactionally)
  }
}
```

I have tried playing with "returning" but I can't get the syntax I need and keep getting type mismatches e.g. the below doesn't compile (because it's probably completely wrong!)

```html
 def save_report(report: Report): Future[Report] = {
    dbConfig.db.run(reportsTable.returning(reportsTable).insertOrUpdate(report))
  }
```

Any help appreciated - I'm new to Scala and Slick so apologies if I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved - posting it incase it helps anyone else trying to do something similar:

```html
//will return the new session_id on insert, and None on update
  def save_report(report: Report): Future[Option[Long]] = {
    val insertQuery = (reportsTable returning reportsTable.map(_.session_id)).insertOrUpdate(report)
    dbConfig.db.run(insertQuery)
  }
```

Works well - insertOrUpdate doesn't returning anything it seems on update, so if I need to get the updated data after the update operation I can then run a subsequent query to get the information using the session id.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return whole Report, first return Id (`returning(reportsTable.map(_.session_id))`) and then get whole object

Check if report exists in the database if it exists update it, if not go ahead inserting the report into the database.

*Note do above operations in all or none fashion by using Transactions*

```
def getReportDBIO(id: Long): DBIO[Report] = reportsTable.filter(_.session_id === id).result.head

def save_report(report: Report): Future[Report] = {
  val query = reportsTable.filter(_.session_id === report.session_id)
  val existsAction = query.exists.result
  val insertOrUpdateAction = 
  (for { 
     exists <- existsAction
     result <- exists match {
        case true => 
        query.update(report).flatMap {_ => getReportDBIO(report.session_id)}.transactionally
        case false => {
           val insertAction = reportsTable.returning(reportsTable.map(_.session_id)) += report
           val finalAction = insertAction.flatMap( id => getReportDBIO(id)).transactionally //transactionally is important
            finalAction
        }
     }
  } yield result).transactionally

  dbConfig.db.run(insertOrUpdateAction)
}
```

*Update your insertOrUpdate function accordingly*

Comment: Many thanks for this - however insertorupdate is a Slick inbuilt function, so not something I can update as such.  I was hoping to use it because it either updates the record or inserts if it doesn't exist - but I can't find any way of returning the whole row using it, or even the session ID.

Comment: @jnhamilton you could use `save_report` instead of `insertOrUpdate` for this case.

Comment: Ah I see thanks, I'll try this tomorrow and update the ticket

Comment: Tried this out thanks - it actually inserts a new record when you try and update rather than updating the existing record, but it has given me some ideas to try :)

Answer (score 2):

You can return the full row, but it is an Option, as the documentation states, it will be empty on an update and will be a Some(...) representing the inserted row on an insert.

So the correct code would be

```
    def save_report(report: Report): Future[Option[Report]] = {dbConfig.db.run(reportsTable.returning(reportsTable).insertOrUpdate(report))}
```